# c# NetworkStream BeginRead seemingly overwriting byte

Tags: c#, asynchronous

For some program, I want to send data over from a python program to a c# program. I put all of my data into a list in python and send it over after converting to bytes (packing them as doubles, so I have 8 bytes per number I am sending over). Having some understanding of how sockets and TCP streams work, the very first number in the list is the amount of bytes that the rest of the list takes up. Hence, the first 8 bytes of my stream tell me how many bytes I need to read to get all other data.

However, when I call BeginRead and it calls the callback, it has read 8 bytes less than I asked it to read. For instance, those first 8 bytes tell me there is 116432 bytes to read, but when I call EndRead it returns 116424.

Okay, so what? There's eight bytes missing, this amounts to one double being lost. This is a problem in and of itself, but I even figured out where this double has gone.

In python, at a specific point (while it is still doubles) in my data, I see I am sending this: **"...,1961.0, 0.0128, 2033.0, 0.0442, 2034.0,..."** when I inspect that same point in c# (after converting my bytes back to doubles), I see this: **"..,1961.0, 2033.0002, 0.0442,2034.0,..."**.

To me, it seems clear that somehow these 8 bytes got mashed together into one, fusing the two number (bit-wise maybe?) together somehow. I have also noticed that the index of where this occurs in the byte data is roughly at the 64k-65k mark. So I'm suspecting that with 64kbytes being the max packet size of TCP packets, the stream has some kind of hiccup there and overwrites one part of my buffer without clearing it, leading to some literal mix up? Does anybody have any idea how I could fix this problem or what mistake I made that is causing this to happen?

I will paste the two relevant functions here.

```
private void Listen(int port)
{
    try
    {
        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        var client = _server.AcceptTcpClient();

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        var pLength = new byte[8];          

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while(_running)
        {
            if(!stream.DataAvailable && stream.Read(pLength, 0, 8) <= 0)
                continue;            
            var nOfBytes = (int) BitConverter.ToDouble(pLength, 0);
            pLength = new byte[8];

            if (nOfBytes <= 0) 
            {
                continue;
            }

            var localBytes = new byte[nOfBytes];

            var scriptData = new ScriptData(stream, localBytes);
            stream.BeginRead(localBytes, 0, nOfBytes, new AsyncCallback(GotAllBytes), scriptData);
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        _errorBool = true;
        _errorString = "Port: " + port + "\n" + e.Message + e.StackTrace;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Stop listening for new clients.
        _server.Stop();
    }
}

private void GotAllBytes(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var scriptData = (ScriptData)result.AsyncState;
    if (OnlinePaused)
    {
        scriptData.Stream.EndRead(result);
        return;
    }
    var bytesRead = scriptData.Stream.EndRead(result);
    _rawDataQueue.Enqueue(scriptData.Buffer.ToList());
}
```

Thanks for reading, I hope you can help out.

Comment: All that `Read` guarantees to give you (if successful) is 1 byte. You have to loop (and adjust where in the buffer you're asking for data to go and how much to read) if there are a certain number of bytes you want/need to read. Or in other words `GotAllBytes` is optimistically but incorrectly named. Even for your initial read of 8 bytes, you're not guaranteed to get all of them at once.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [`BinaryReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I know this is the case. However, I find it hard to believe I consistently just miss the last 8 bytes of my data while those two specific numbers seem to get mixed together. To my understanding, BeginRead will only call "GotAllBytes" once it has, indeed, read nOfBytes amount of bytes. Do correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed, it is! I already use BinaryReader in another section fo my code. As a matter of fact, after enqueueing data in _rawDataQueue, I dequeue is elsewhere and use a BinaryReader to convert it back to doubles. This is how I noticed that those particular two points seem to get mixed together.

Comment: Take a look at how `BinaryReader.FillBuffer` is implemented; you'll see it uses exactly the kind of loop Damien has mentioned to ensure it reads the necessary bytes. `Stream.Read` is *not* guaranteed to give you a particular amount of bytes; only the various reader classes built on top of streams do so. What you find "hard to believe" is probably exactly what happens when packets get cut up on your local interface; you're just (un)lucky data isn't more fragmented. Code like this can even run perfectly fine (by accident) and then fail in other circumstances.

Comment: ...having said that, your code has other weirdness that makes me suspect the problem *might* well be somewhere else in code that we're not seeing. Also, are you sure those "missing" 8 bytes aren't the 8 bytes for the length that the sender is counting and you are not? (I'm still in favor of replacing this entire thing with a simple loop over `BinaryReader.ReadDouble()`, by the way, and removing all other intermediate buffering.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am currently in the process of trying out what you are saying, but after a closer look, I am seeing what you're talking about. This may even make my code in general more efficient. Thank you very much for helping me out so far. I will make another comment when this works... or not.

Comment: It worked! Now I will figure out how to mark your comment as an answer and/or close this question. You were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeroen Mostert in the comments of the original question, this problem has been resolved by not working async but instead implementing a BinaryReader.

```
private void Listen(int port)
{
    try
    {
        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        var client = _server.AcceptTcpClient();

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        var pLength = new byte[8];          

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while(_running)
        {
            if(!stream.DataAvailable && stream.Read(pLength, 0, 8) <= 0)
                continue;            
            var nOfBytes = (int) BitConverter.ToDouble(pLength, 0);
            pLength = new byte[8];

            if (nOfBytes <= 0) 
            {
                continue;
            }

            var localBytes = new byte[nOfBytes];

            var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            ProcessData(reader);
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        _errorBool = true;
        _errorString = "Port: " + port + "\n" + e.Message + e.StackTrace;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Stop listening for new clients.
        _server.Stop();
    }
}
```

Thank you for everybody who was trying to help.

Comment: `localBytes` and `nOfBytes` have both become unused -- the current code will gobble up all doubles until the stream is done with no heed for the initial length, which may or may not be what you want. If you do want to respect the length, simply use `BinaryReader` to read that value as well (and loop `value / 8` times) -- the current initial call to `Read` is still wrong because it may return less than 8 bytes, which would make the rest of the stream return garbage. (You do need to get very unlucky for a packet to fragment in the first 8 bytes, but it's not impossible.)

Comment: You are correct. I threw this up here when I saw it was all working. I had some other bits of code in there that allowed to me to see how many doubles were in my stream, so I'm now using those rather than using an amount of bytes. In hindsight it was stupid to have redundancy there. I completely rely on the BinaryReader as you say and have removed any unused code. Suppose that's my bad for not including more context. Thanks again man!